# trace an address using ip address

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

how to trace the information of an individual using ip adress and email id can any one help me... i tried for a example using my friends ip address , and i was able to get only this information alone....

Location of the IP address 59.162.171.249:
Visakhapatnam in India.

but how to trace his address perfectly
plz help me

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. IP addresses are not bound to any geography, more than that they are handed out by different organizations on each continent, but there's no restriction on were one can use that IP, so an American ISP can choose to use their IP in Europe if they want.

The only thing you can do is use a GeoIP database where a company have manually noted were each IP address/network is, and these is usually just where a main router is probably located. The end user usually get different IPs by DHCP every time they log on so the IPs are rotated between different customers.

Note that any GeoIP database may be utterly **wrong** on some IP addresses as well. There's no perfect way to know for sure where any IP or user is sitting. You cannot even be 100% sure about the country they are in.

Comment: ohhhhhhh k sir i think this is a legal issue so if v get problem from ip address v can complaint to police no other way to trace him is it right 

thank u sir

Answer (score 1):

You mean his street address? No, that's not possible. You can identify his ISP from his IP address but you'd need access to their records to correlate an assigned IP address to a user account and the account details (such as name, street address). Unless you're law enforcement you're out-of-luck.

Comment: ohhhhhhh k sir i think this is a legal issue so if v get problem from ip address v can complaint to police no other way to trace him is it right

 thank u sir

Answer (score 0):

The ISP who issues the IP address probably knows, but shouldn't tell you or anyone without
a court being involved.

Comment: ohhhhhhh k sir 
i think this is a legal issue so if v get problem from ip address v can complaint to police no other way to trace him is it right 
thank u sir